# Smoothly painting a path of straight line segments in Qt5

Tags: qt5

I have a series of straight line segments of varying thickness connected end-to-end to create meandering path. Does anyone know a way to paint this as a smooth meandering line, sort of like vectorizing it? I am using QPainter. I haven't had any success finding an appropriate function in QPainterPath.

The data looks something like this:

```
[(QPointF, width), (QPointF, width), (QPointF, width), ... ]
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Added example image

I wanted to leave it open to creative responses, but I am just looking to move from linear interpolation (QPainter::drawLine()) to spline interpolation.

[image: Spline VS linear interpolation]

Comment: Could you please elaborate how such a thing should look like?

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Here is a great forum post outlining this, although without code examples: https://forum.qt.io/topic/76434/how-to-paint-smooth-rendering-of-connected-qlinef-s/8

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...
Don't draw a line, draw a filled polygon that encloses your line data with the right thickness. Drawback: That requires calculations on your data beforehand.

Comment: Hmm, not quite what I was asking. Filling a polygon, I assume with four points to very thickness, will still be as smooth as linear interpolation, where I am looking for spline interpolation.

Comment: In reading your comment again, I'm wondering if I misunderstood you. Are you suggesting that I use a polygon with four points for each segment, or a single polygon for the entire pencil stroke, or something else altogether? Were you pointing in the direction of using some existing smoothing algorithm based on a "filled polygon?"